# XSLT/Xpath Select elements based on the values of two attributes

Tags: xslt, xpath-2.0

I wish to return all `<nodes>` which have the tags with the attributes k=network & v=LU. Note LU could be part of a string. This XML just returns a list of `<tag k="network" v="LU"/>`

If there are any other improvements I can make, please note them.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"> 
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="osm">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node/tag[@k='network' and @v='LU']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Original XML:

```
<osm>
   <node>
      <tag k="railway" v="station"/>
      <tag k="network" v="LU"/>
   </node>
   <node>
      <tag k="railway" v="station"/>
      <tag k="network" v="NR"/>
      <tag k="operator" v="LU"/>
   </node>
   <node>
      <tag k="railway" v="station"/>
      <tag k="network" v="NR,LU"/>
      <tag k="operator" v="LU"/>
   </node>
     <...snip...>
</osm>
```

Desired output

```
<osm>
   <node>
      <tag k="railway" v="station"/>
      <tag k="network" v="LU"/>
   </node>
   <node>
      <tag k="railway" v="station"/>
      <tag k="network" v="NR,LU"/>
      <tag k="operator" v="LU"/>
   </node>
</osm>
```

Comment: Please indicate which version of XSLT you are able to use. It usually affects the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am I right in thinking that your requirement is to select and copy all `<node>` elements that have a child `<tag>` element with attribute `@k='network'` and an attribute `@v` which is a list of tokens including the token `LU`?

I would do this simply as

```
<xsl:template match="osm">
  <osm>
    <xsl:copy-of select="node[tag[@k='network'][contains(@v,'LU')]]"/>
  </osm>
</xsl:template>
```

But the `contains()` test might need to be made more precise, for example if a value like `v="LUCKY"` can appear. With XSLT 2.0 I would use the predicate `[tokenize(@v, ',')='LU']`

Comment: Question answer: Yes.
It took a bit of head scratching to realize 'contains' was missing a closing bracket, but it now works
This & all other examples I could find, hard codes the upper element (osm). is it possible to make it generic for any label?

Comment: you can use `<xsl:template match="/*">`. Inside it, use `<xsl:element name="{name()}"><xsl:copy-of select="node[tag[@k='network'][contains(@v,'LU']]"/></xsl:template>`

Comment: Corrected. Glad you scratched your head over it; I hate it when people use code snippets without stopping to understand them.

Comment: @JoelM.Lamsen Could I ask you to clarify/check please, as I'm struggling to get it to work. Should the element have a closing forward slash or closing element? Many online examples use 'local_name'. is that appropriate in this case? Is the `match` correct?

Comment: @DaveF You clearly need to get hold of some documentation: you're struggling because you're trying to make it work by trial and error.

Comment: I'm having to do it by 'trial & error' /because/ I've been reading documentation. Such as this site!

Comment: Given the two erroneous replies I finally found the time to sort this out. For 
newbies coming here via an internet search the correct routine is:`<xsl:template 
match="/*">
<xsl:element name="{name()}">
<xsl:copy-of select="node[tag[@k='network'][contains(@v,'LU']]"/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>`

I note one who replied in error is a writer of "documentation". I really hope he 
employed a competent proof reader.

Comment: That's why you should go to real documentation and not rely on StackOverflow answers. It's likely to have been much more thoroughly checked.